# WMT2018 news commentary Chinese dataset weird character

Tags: python, text, character-encoding, nlp, machine-translation

I'm working on the WMT2018 dataset for Chinese to do machine translation. I found that there are a lot of weird characters in the data which look like the following:

[image]

I thought this was the encoding problem, so I converted it to a text file with UTF-8 that supports Chinese characters, but this problem remains.

Any idea on how to solve this issue?

Comment: The original source isn't read properly in the right encoding before converting into utf8.

Comment: Maybe removing them would be okay, trying to find the right characters there is quite impossible unless you know where's the source of the document.

Comment: Which file did the WMT2018 come from?

Comment: this one http://data.statmt.org/wmt18/translation-task/training-parallel-nc-v13.tgz